# Meta table VS table with many fields, on a large scale. Performance-wise

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, scalability, entity-attribute-value

Here is a concrete example:

Wordpress stores user information(meta) in a table called wp_usermeta where you get the meta_key field (ex: first_name) and the meta_value (John)

However, only after 50 or so users, the table already packs about 1219 records.

So, my question is: On a large scale, performance wise, would it be better to have a table with all the meta as a field, or a table like WordPress does with all the meta as a row ?

Indexes are properly set in both cases. There is little to no need of adding new metas. Keep in mind that a table like wp_usermeta must use a text/longtext field type (large footprint) in order to accommodate any type of data that could be entered.

My assumptions are that the WordPress approach is only good when you don't know what the user might need. Otherwise:

- retrieving all the meta requires more I/O because the fields aren't stored in a single row. The field isn't optimised.
- You can't really have an index on the meta_value field without suffering from major drawbacks (indexing a longtext ? unless it's a partial index...but then, how long?)
- Soon, your database is cluttered with many rows, cursing your research even for the most precise meta
- Developer-friendly is absent. You can't really do a join request to get everything you need and displayed properly.

I may be missing a point though. I'm  not a database engineer, and I know only the basics of SQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're talking about Entity-Attribute-Value.

```
- Entity    = User, in your Wordpress Example  
- Attribute = 'First Name', 'Last Name', etc  
- Value     = 'John', 'Smith', etc
```

Such a schema is very good at allowing a dynamic number of Attributes for any given Entity.  You don't need to change the schema to add an Attribute.  Depending on the queries, the new attributes can often be used without changing any SQL at all.

It's also perfectly fast enough at retrieving those attributes values, provided that you know the Entity and the Attribute that you're looking for.  It's just a big fancy Key-Value-Pair type of set-up.

It is, however, not so good where you need to search the records based on the Value contents.  Such as, `get me all users called 'John Smith'`.  Trivial to ask in English.  Trivial to code against a 'normal' table; `first_name = 'John' AND last_name = 'Smith'`.  But non-trivial to write in SQL against EAV, and awful relative performance; *(Get all the Johns, then all the Smiths, then intersect them to get Entities that match both.)*

There is a lot said about EAV on-line, so I won't go in to massive detail here.  But a general rule of thumb is:  If you can avoid it, you probably should.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the number of names packed into wp_usermeta on average.

Text field searches are notoriously slow.  Indexes are generally faster.

But some data warehouses index the crap out of every field and Wordpress might be doing the same thing.

I would vote for meta as a field not a row.

Good SQL, good night.
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Examples from two major software in the GPL arena would illustrate how big difference there is in between the two designs :

Wordpress & oScommerce

Both have their flaws and strengths, and both are massively dominant in their respective areas and a lot of things are done with them. But one of the fundamental and biggest differences in between them is their approach to database table design. Of course, when comparing these, their code architecture also plays a role in how fast they do searches, but both are hampered by their own drawbacks and boosted by their own advantages, so the comparison is more or less accurate for production environments.

Wordpress uses EAV. The general data (called posts with different post types) is stored as the main entity, and all else is stored in post meta tables. Some fundamental data is stored in the main table, like revisions, post type etc, but almost all the rest is stored in metas.

VERY good for adding, modifying data, and therefore functionality.

But try a search with a complex SQL join which needs to pick up 3-4 different values from the meta table and get the resulting set. Its an iron dog. Search comes out VERY slow depending on the data you are searching for.

This is one of the reasons why you dont see many wordpress plugins which need to host complex data, and the ones which actually do, tend to create their own tables.

oScommerce on the other hand, keeps almost all product related data in products table. And majority of oScommerce mods modify this table and add their fields. There is products_attribute table, however this is also rather flat, and doesnt have any meta design. Its just linked to products over product ids.

As a result, despite being an aged spaghetti code from a very long time ago, oScommerce comes up with stunningly fast search results even when you search for complicated and combined product criteria. Actually, most of oScommerce's normal display code (like what it shows in product details page) comes from quite complicated SQLs pulling data from around 2-3 tables in complicated join statements. Comparably much more simpler sql with even one join could make wordpress duke it out with the database.

Therefore its rather plain conclusion : EAV is very good for easy extension and modification of data for extended functionality (ie as in wordpress). Flat, big monolithic tables are MUCH better for databases which will represent complicated records, and will have complicated searches with multiple criteria run on them.

Its a question of application.

Answer (score -1):

For what i've seen the EAV model doesn't affect the performance. Unless you need the null values. In that case you should make a join with the table that holds all the type_meta.

I don't agree with the answer of Dems.

If you want to make the fullname of the user you don't ask for every name that matchs the name.

For that you should use a 5th or 6th NF.

Or you may even have a table of the user entity where you have:

- id
- username
- password
- salt

and there you go. That's the base, and for all the user "extra" data you should have a user_meta and user_type_meta entities. Then with the user.

Comment: Wow, raising the dead here :)  Could you show in your answer how to find all entities which match *both* of these conditions?  The attribute `first_name` is `'John'` and the attribute `last_name` is `'smith'`.  Without using the process I described?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of finding every John Smith in the code, but you should search all the John then all the Smith and later intersect them. Is more like find All the John then pop off who are not smith.

Comment: Like:
$users = $repoUser->findBy(array('firstName' => 'John'));
foreach($users as $user){
    if($user->getLastName() == 'Smith'){
        $johnSmiths[] = $user;
    }
}

Comment: 1) That's not SQL.  2) The intersection description ***is*** the method I described in my answer.  3) Achieving that intersection in EAV is ***significantly*** less performant than a single table with two fields and a composite index on those two fields.

Comment: Again, i don't agree that your method of calling the same table 2 times is the solution. It's like calling only once that table, and with the data that you already have dispose those that doesn't have the lastname. 

Of course it is faster to have the 2 attributes in the same row. And it's even faster if you index them, and even more using NoSQL. But, to go back to my point, instead of separating into 2 fields, just use one. Called username. And don't put that in the metas table, put that in the user table where is the password.

Comment: I never said I'd call the same table.  `SELECT id FROM table WHERE (attribute='lat_name' AND value='fGROUP BY id